# Limitar sidebar antes do footer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Eu tenho o seguinte código, porém tenho um footer de 650px, e ao rolar a pagina até o final o bloco fixo fica em cima do footer, como poderia resolver esse problema?

```
    <script>
 $(function(){

  var jElement = $('.ingresso-fix');

  $(window).scroll(function(){
    if ( $(this).scrollTop() > 620 ){
      jElement.css({
        'position':'fixed',
        'top':'30px'
      });
    }

    else{
      jElement.css({
        'position':'absolute',
        'top':'auto'
      });
    }
  });

});
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu não tenho certeza se é isso que você quer fazer.

Mas você pode calcular a diferença entre a altura da página e a altura do seu rodapé e então dizer que se o scroll for maior do que o resultado desse cálculo, o side bar deve ficar oculto. Algo assim:

```
var altura = $(document).height() - $(".footer").height();
$(window).scroll(function(){
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > altura){
    $(".sidebar").fadeOut(500);
  }else{
    $(".sidebar").fadeIn(500);
  }
});
```

Da uma olhada nesse Fiddle e vê se é isso mesmo: https://jsfiddle.net/ttae38b3/1/

Answer (score 0):

Desenvolvi um script usando apenas javascript com um exemplo de layout aplicando esta situação que descreveu.

Vou tentar explicar o que ele faz, talvez fique meio complexo para entender, estou à disposição para explicar melhor.

O script pega as informações de distância do top e altura do elemento que ficará fixo, também pega a altura do `footer`, subtrai estas informações pela altura do da janela, ou neste caso, a `div#main`, assim ele terá o valor minimo para quando o `scroll` atingir este começar a tratar a altura do elemento fixo.

```js
var initTop = 0;
var fixed = document.getElementById('fixed');
var footer = document.getElementById('footer');
var main = document.getElementById('main');

window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  var alturaMin = main.offsetHeight - footer.offsetHeight - fixed.offsetHeight - fixed.offsetTop;
  var altMin = (main.offsetHeight - (footer.offsetHeight + fixed.offsetHeight));
 
  if(this.scrollY > 0) {
   fixed.classList.add('fixed');
  } else {
   fixed.classList.remove('fixed');
  }
  
  initTop = initTop == 0 ? fixed.offsetTop : initTop;
  
  if(this.scrollY > alturaMin) {
    var sub = alturaMin - this.scrollY + fixed.offsetTop;
    fixed.style.top = sub + 'px';
  } else if(this.scrollY < altMin) {
    if(fixed.offsetTop != initTop) {
      fixed.style.top = initTop + 'px';
    }
  } else {
    fixed.style.top = (altMin - this.scrollY) + 'px';
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.main {
  position: relative;
  height: 1300px;
  width: 100%;
}

.offer {
  background-color: green;
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
}

.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  width: 50%;
  height: 200px;
  z-index: 101;
  top: 50px;
}

.footer {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: tomato;
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main" id="main">
  <div class="offer" id="fixed">
  </div>
  <div class="footer" id="footer">
  </div>
</div>
```